# Record selection based on Next Sunday through end of 2 months out

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to pull all records from the `{@Calc Promise Date}` field that have a date range of next Sunday through the end of next month. I have the end of next month part, and tried the next Sunday part using some similar examples on this site, but I am still off target on the next Sunday part.

Original try that would have a start of 5 days after today:

```
{@Calc Promise Date}>=DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),Day(currentdate)+5)
and {@Calc Promise Date}<DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate)+2,1)
```

This was modified from help given to another user, but does not cover how to adjust the start date of the range to next Sunday.

I tried the following and have errors as I do not understand the correct layout, or if this will help in getting my desired start date.

```
{@Calc Promise Date} >= if DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1),1) = 1
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1+7)
else if DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1),1) = 2
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1+6)
else if DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1),1) = 3     
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1+5)
else if DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1),1) = 4    
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1+4)
else if DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1),1) = 5     
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1+3)
else if DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1),1) = 6     
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1+2)
else if DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1),1) = 7    
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1+1)
and {@Calc Promise Date}<DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate)+2,1)
```

Comment: what are errors for second formula?

Comment: Thank you for looking at this.  The error I get has something to do with the way I have written my selection formula.  When I try to save it I get "There is an error in this formula.  Do you want to save it anyway?"; followed by "A boolean is required here." and the following formula section highlighted.
    DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1+1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost done as per my knowledge writing this formula in `Record Selection` doesn't work instead create saperate formulas and write on liner in record selection.

Create a formula **Start Date**:

```
if DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1),1) = 1
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1+7)
else if DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1),1) = 2
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1+6)
else if DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1),1) = 3     
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1+5)
else if DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1),1) = 4    
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1+4)
else if DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1),1) = 5     
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1+3)
else if DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1),1) = 6     
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1+2)
else if DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1),1) = 7    
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),1+1)
and {@Calc Promise Date}<DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate)+2,1)
```

Create a Formula **End Date**:

```
DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate)+2,1)
```

Now your Record Selection:

```
{@Calc Promise Date}>={@Start Date}
and {@Calc Promise Date}<{@End Date}
```

Comment: A huge "THANK YOU!!!".  I modified the Start date a bit and am getting the desired end date selection range.
if DayOfWeek (DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),Day(currentdate))) = 1
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),Day(currentdate)+7)
else if  DayOfWeek(DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),Day(currentdate))) = 2
then DateSerial(Year(currentdate),Month(currentdate),Day(currentdate)+6)

And so on